# ¿Como puedo guardar el contenido de un fileupload en un arreglo de bytes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, array, webforms, fileupload

Buenas noches a todos mi consulta es la siguiente .

Tengo un formulario `asp.net web forms` en `vb.net` en el cual tengo un control `asp:fileupload` como este:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="UpLoadEstudiantes" runat="server" AllowMultiple="False" CssClass="fileContainer"/>
```

Lo que deseo en el `code behind` es obtener ese archivo del `fileupload` y convertirlo a un arreglo de `bytes` para mandarlo a un método que recibe este arreglo de `bytes` y lo procesa.

El problema es que trato de obtener el contenido del `fileupload` y convertirlo a un arreglo de `bytes` pero no consigo pasar lleno el arreglo de bytes con el archivo.

Esta es una de las maneras que intente llenar un arreglo de `bytes` con el contenido del `fileupload`.

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
UpLoadEstudiantes.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms)
Dim byts = ms.ToArray()
ms.Dispose()
```

Y tengo este error frecuentemente al usar el `InputStream` o el `ContentFile`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En la propiedad `FileBytes` del `FileUpload` ya tienes el contenido del archivo en un array de bytes:

```
If UpLoadEstudiantes.HasFile Then
    Dim filelen As Integer = UpLoadEstudiantes.PostedFile.ContentLength
    Dim byts(filelen-1) As Byte
    byts = UpLoadEstudiantes.FileBytes

End If
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Asier , actualizo la pregunta ya que logre obtener un array de bytes desde el fileupload , el tema ahora es que al mandarlo a un método , cuando intento llenar un con el array de bytes que mando se pierde el contenido . Tengo una excepción pero no se si está relacionada .